# How to improve the under-fitting issue of my RNN Autoencoder on random squences?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to use RNN (seq-to-seq) as Autoencoder to reconstruct random sequences (classification). However, the model is suffering from under-fitting issue in which it can't improve the training loss (settles around 2.6) and predicts mostly 0s (length variation is high so I padded with a lot 0s while doing min-batch training).

The random sequences are initiated with the following code:

```
vocab = 200
raw = np.array(range(vocab))+3 # 200 Unique Events=3-203 + [pad=0],[EOS=1],[SOS=2]
EventOptions = [str(i) for i in raw]

class data_simulator(object):

   def __init__(self,seq_list,seq_min,seq_max):
    self.seq_min = seq_min
    self.seq_max = seq_max
    self.seq_list = seq_list
    print("Data Generator Registered...")

   def Gen(self,volume):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Instance':range(volume),
                               'Sequence':[' | '.join(np.random.choice(self.seq_list, np.random.randint(self.seq_min, self.seq_max))) for i in xrange(volume)]
                               })

Generator = data_simulator(EventOptions,20,200) # lengths varies from 20 to 200
RawData_Normal = Generator.Gen(5000) # 5000 sequences
```

I started with an initial learning to identify the learning rate and optimizer for this data. So, I initiate an basic architecture of RNN autoencoder as:

- Single layer GRU cell with tanh activation
- Basic Encoder-Decoder seq-to-seq
- 100 neurons in hidden layer
- 20 embedding features
- 50 random sequences + batch_size = 10 + n_epochs = 100

to test the learning rate range with various optimizers:

```
learning_vector = [0.000001,0.000003,0.000006,0.000008,
                   0.00001,0.00003,0.00006,0.00008,
                   0.0001,0.0003,0.0006,0.0008,
                   0.001,0.003,0.006,0.008,
                   0.01,0.03,0.06,0.08,
                   0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8]
```

The result is below with increasing learning rate [0.000001-0.8] and all optimizers settled around 2.6:

[image]

Then, I picked "Adam" with the best learning rate on previous plot - 0.0005 to retrain the model with more capacities like below:

- 3 layers GRU cell with He initialization and tanh activation
- Encoder-Decoder seq-to-seq with attention
- 250 neurons in each hidden layer
- 20 embedding features
- 5000 random sequences + batch_size = 200 + n_epochs = 3000

Then, I have got very similar "underfitting" result like below which settles around 2.6 for both train and validation loss (make sense since both are random sequences):

[image]

However, I was expecting the increased model capacity should enables the model to "memorize" the random noises so that we can further improve training performance till overfitting the random sequences. Yet, this wasn't happen and the training loss was settled around 2.6 no matter how many more epochs I train the model. Is it because the random sequences variations are too informative to be learnt given my current model capacity and train time? Or the high variations in the sequence length resulted a lot of 0 pads which can skewed the prediction? How can I resolve the underfitting issues in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You're giving it random noise, and expects it to learn how to re-create it? I don't think that's possible, it will try to learn patterns and those shouldn't exist in random noise.